# Nesting the ternary operator in Python

Tags: python, nested-statement

In the Zen of Python, Tim Peters states that `Flat is better than nested.`. If I have understood that correctly, then in Python, this:

```
<statement-1> if <condition> else <statement-2>
```

is generally preferred over this:

```
if <condition>:
    <statement-1>
else:
    <statement-2>
```

However, in other languages, I have been told not to nest the ternary operator, and the instead use the traditional `if...else`. My question, then, is should I use this:

```
(<statement-1> if <condition-1> else <statement-2>) if <condition-2> else <statement-3>
```

or

```
if <condition-2>:
    if <condition-1>:
        <statement-1>
    else:
        <statement-2>
else:
    <statement-3>
```

? Particularly if the statements and conditions are long, and the first line would need splitting?

Comment: I would use the second: it's much clearer and easier to maintain. I'm not really sure what he means by that.

Comment: Agreed go with the second.

Comment: please use the second.  I can understand it after reading -zero- words; the indentation conveys all of the information.

Comment: It could possibly be interpreted to mean that you should try to not nest your ifs--maybe have if <condition-2> and <condition-1>:\n <statement-1>\n elif <condition-2> and not <condition-1>: \n <statement-2>\n else:\n <statement-3>

Comment: The ternary operator is used to combine expressions, not statements (syntax error).

Comment: You could rewrite the nested ternary as `<expr3> if not <c2> else <expr1> if <c3> else <expr2>` so you don't need parentheses and it reads sequentially. Personally I prefer dense rather than sparse in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Flat is better than nested" is about module organization and perhaps data structures, not your source code.  The standard library, for example, mostly exists as top-level modules with very little nesting.

Don't nest the ternary operator, or even use it at all if you can avoid it.  Complex is better than complicated.  :)

Comment: I don't agree with the 'or even use it at all if you can avoid it' - it's a lovely piece of syntax if used correctly.

Comment: @Ben in my experience: if the surrounding code is simple, the ternary doesn't buy you much.  if the surrounding code is complicated, ternary will make it worse.

Comment: I like to use it in return statements where the value returned depends on a simple test.

Comment: ternary operator is part and parcel of fp. please do use.

Answer (score 30):

Your *first* example (the horrid one-liner) is nested too.  Horizontally nested.  Your second example is vertically nested.  They're *both* nested.

So which is better?  The second one!  Why?  Because "sparse is better than dense" breaks the tie.

It's easy when you're Tim Peters - LOL ;-)

Comment: Not fair, we can't all be Tim Peters!  We can only but try to aspire.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, this is "flater":

```
if <condition_2> and <condition_1>:
  <statement_1>
elif <condition_2>:
  <statement_2>
else:
  <statement_3>
```

The order of the conditions to check is important, e.g. should you put `<condition_2>` only as the first order of checking, then `<statement_1>` will never be called.

Comment: Even more so if the conditional involved more levels of nesting; I think this is one of the most reasonable options.